# What kind of format is this date in?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
2018-06-04T01:00:45.500Z
```

**Moment.js** returns a date object when calling `moment()`, but sometimes returns this timestamp.

How can I make sure I'm receiving a timestamp like this and not a date object?

For example, output of `calling console.log(moment())`:

[image]

Comment: So – this date format is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Can you give a bit more information as to what makes your script output this timestamp vs what's expected? Some code snippets would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ');
```

This returns an output in this format :

> 2018-06-04T12:49:53+10:00

Answer (score 1):

That format is ISO, is the universal format to represent a date in javascript. It's the same format that you get from `Date.toISOString()`

You can get this date format as follow

```
console.log(moment().toISOString())
```

reference https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/